# Anki won't load images from text file : Allow HTML in fields option

Tags: images, import, anki

I haven't been able to import pictures from a CSV file for the whole day, not understanding what is wrong.

I've checked the Anki Manual, and tried everything, but I can't find the "Allow HTML in fields" in the Preferences or Options...

Answer (score 1):

My bad.
Soon after posting, and trying once more, I finally saw the "Allow HTML in fields" in the Import Window, and ticked it.

I post it here so that others who couldn't find it know where to find it...

[image: Picture of Anki Import Window with Allow HTML box inline]